# Windows RIO socket Registered I/O sending delay RIOSend

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp, winsock2

I send portions of TCP data across distributed network using RIOSend.
The Nagle is turned off to reach minimum latency.
When the destination is local all looks good, but in case of really remote(about 40ms ping) destination I see this problem:
When I send portion of data, the next portion delaeyd, no matter of RIOSend flags- RIO_MSG_DONTNOTIFY, RIO_MSG_DEFER or 0.
Looks like the sending waiiting for ACK from other side....
When I use simple Send all is good.
Please help me to solve this problem!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a RIO_MSG_COMMIT call; RIO_MSG_DEFER will delay your data, RIO_MSG_DONTNOTIFY means an IOCP or Event won't be raised on completion, though it will still be added to queue.

If your retransmit timeout on your TCP connection set low? Do you eventually get the data? (e.g. after 300ms)

Are you disabling Nagle with something like the following code:

`int True = -1; 
int result = setsockopt(socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char*)&True, 4)`

Also are you using RIO on the receiver? If so what methods are you using IOCP, Event or Polling?

Remember after you have received a IOCP message you need to call RIONotify to receive another one.

Aside: Have some managed interop from C# testing [here](http://www.ageofascent.com/azure-cloud-high-speed-networking/), with code [here](https://github.com/benaadams/benchmarks/tree/managed-rio-experimental/experimental/ManagedRIOHttpServer); might provide some things to check; language might not be same but the calls should essentially be the same.

The [actual sending](https://github.com/benaadams/benchmarks/blob/managed-rio-experimental/experimental/ManagedRIOHttpServer/RegisteredIO/RIOTcpConnection.cs#L84) function may help.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your time, nobody works with RIO ;)

Comment: Of course, I use rio_msg_commitonly after rio_msg_defer... My latest experience is: all looks like I can't disable nagle for rio sockets. No errors but nagle works. As a result - huge delays. Traditional sockets with nagle on works so.

Comment: Yes, I disable Nagle exact as you say. Also, when I work via local host the performance is great, the degradation occurs when I send packets to remote host. I see your exmples, looks like you don't need for low latency, I see no TCP_NODELAY flag set. In Receiver I use traditional TCP.

Comment: Nagle is switched off on socket prior to activating RIO or starting to listen: https://github.com/benaadams/benchmarks/blob/managed-rio-experimental/experimental/ManagedRIOHttpServer/RegisteredIO/RIOImports.cs#L128

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. But do you see differenece if you don't do this?

Comment: Latency of sending don't changed if I remove TCP_NODELAY set. In traditional sockets latency changed dramatically if I don't turn Nagle off

Comment: What's your TCP window rules for network type in use? ```netsh interface tcp show heuristics```

Comment: TCP Window Scaling heuristics Parameters
    ----------------------------------------------
    Window Scaling heuristics         : disabled
    Qualifying Destination Threshold  : 3
    Profile type unknown              : normal
    Profile type public               : normal
    Profile type private              : normal
    Profile type domain               : normal

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't disable Nagle on RIO TCP sockets.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6a551731-c339-44b8-b1a5-68240962e458/unable-to-disable-nagle-algorithm-while-using-registered-io-winsock-extension-for-tcp-communication?forum=wsk

I have the same problem.  I wrote a upd/tcp ping test, where a server sends a UDP packet, and the client receives it, and responds back with TCP.

If I have the server send 3 messages right after another, I get the same result with RIO with Nagle disabled as I do with regular sockets with Nagle still enabled.

First packet TCP response comes in quickly, other 2 wait 200 ms for ack timer to expire.

I've run wireshark to verify all this, nothing wrong with windows sizes.

*** EDIT ***
Funny that this came up, since I just revisited this recently.  Turns out there isn't anything wrong with the Nagle for RIO.  My initial coding for a TCP sender is a blocking model that uses 1 buffer.  So what was happening, is when I want to send data, the OS now holds onto that buffer until we get an ack back, so if looking at a network capture it *LOOKED* like Nagle was enabled, because it wouldn't release the only buffer until it was acknowledged.  I'm going to change my TCP sender to use multiple outbound buffers, just need to figure out some details, like what to do if only part of one of the buffers is acknowledge.

Comment: Whether or not it was broken two years ago when this question was asked I don't know, but using setsockopt with TCP_NODELAY works for me with RIOSend when I tried it on Windows 10 1703. Looking at a network trace, the difference is clear.